# QML application on iOS 13.2.2, problem with some keyboard languages

Tags: ios, qt, keyboard, qml, ios13

I have a QML 5.9 application with TextInput elements, which runs on iOS 13.2.2. When I put the keyboard in language Chinese (Zhuyin), or Japanese (Romaji, Kana), I get some random behaviors. I test entering random characters and sometimes, when I click from one TextInput to another TextInput, the application is blocked, and anywhere I click in the app opens the keyboard.

And I have the following error message, even when the app is not blocked:

> stale focus object TextInputWithHandles_QMLTYPE_199(0x280f948f0), doing manual update
>
> MyAppName[...] [Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput

I didn't find anything specific related to this error, so don't know how to fix it. I precise that I put no properties on the TextInput and kept the default ones.